# Changing colors in a template image

Tags: image, graphics, colors

I have some code that can convert a single color in a template image to some other color chosen by a user.  For example, if red RGB(255,0,0) is the template color it is pretty straightforward to convert the red pixels to a new color RGB(r,g,b).  But say my template image has a range of red gradients in it, e.g. the RGB value varies for each pixel in the template.  Is there some formula or process I can use to convert each pixel in the template to something that looks consistent for the new color?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: What template are you talking about?

Comment: Just a bitmap image, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with a good start from vulkanino.  What I had to do was convert my template and new RGB colors to HLS format (hue, luminance, saturation).  Then I checked each bit in the image to see if the hue setting was within the tolerance, and if so, applied the delta hue value to the new color for that bit.  The luminance and saturation could be left alone.  Then I converted the HLS format for the new color back to RGB format, and everything looked good.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a pixel can't have a gradient, but it has an RGB (8 or 16 or 32 bits for each channel) color code, you should set up a tolerance variable, expressed in percent, that will make the color code still considered the same color as the template.

Say in pseudocode:

```
tolerance=10%
IF Rpixel - tolerance <= Rtemplate <= Rpixel + tolerance AND
   Gpixel - tolerance <= Gtemplate <= Gpixel + tolerance AND
   Bpixel - tolerance <= Btemplate <= Bpixel + tolerance THEN

    YEAH they match.
```

Of course this requires a pixel by pixel comparison in the source image.

Edit:
to change the "tolerated" color considering its color shift is simple:

```
deltaR = Abs(Rpixel - Rtemplate)
deltaG = Abs(Gpixel - Gtemplate)
deltaB = Abs(Bpixel - Btemplate)

sourceR = destinationR +/- deltaR;
sourceG = destinationG +/- deltaG;
sourceB = destinationB +/- deltaB;
```

Comment: Sorry if the terminology I used isn't quite right, I was expecting to have to do a pixel by pixel comparison as you suggest.  Anyways that's a good idea to set the tolerance.  But once I determine whether I want to change the pixel, I'd also like to have an equivalent shading or gradient for the new color.  Consider this image:  http://tinyurl.com/6p3amcu.  Now if the user picked a shade of blue as the new color, I'd like to have light blue in the top left of the image, gradually changing to darker blue in the bottom right.  Is there a formula I could apply to do that?

Comment: my answer is still valid, if the pixel color is in the "tolerated" range, then change it with the new color "rescaled" using the same color difference.

Comment: As it turns out, this method didn't really work.  For example, say my template color is red RGB(255,0,0).  Now a faded red value in the template may be something like RGB(255,150,150).  So the tolerance test in the pseudocode will fail for the green and blue pixels.  The idea of using the tolerance was the right way to proceed, but I've added a separate answer with the process.